# ipad programming : objective-c : image in a popover it is possible to do this

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, popover

Is it possible for a popover controller and have an image in it?
What about when clicking on a tableview cell?

Answer (score 1):

I would assume so. I've never done this myself but simply add a UIImageView to the popover view.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageName:(img)];
[popoverViewController.view addSubview:imageView];
```

As I said I haven't tried this myself but see if it works. Also, have you tried anything that is not working? Show some code.